# How do i put the text in the bottom of a button?

Tags: jquery, mobile, button, jquery-mobile, alignment

I have looked/searched for alignment, position(ing) etc.

See picture:

[image]

Comment: Could you post the code, please?

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
input
{
display: block;
padding-top: 300px;
}
```

It should work.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/bkePe/1/

Comment: I did not create this code, but my case is similar. So the question is, how do you place the text on the button press me 2 to the bottom. http://jsfiddle.net/3DSGT/

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into layouts? Create a container and stack a button and a label on it.

http://layout.jquery-dev.net/documentation.cfm#Properties_Methods

Answer (score 0):

How about using the built-in positioning?

```
data-iconpos="top"
```

Source: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/buttons/buttons-icons.html

Comment: Ok, got it working: 

<head>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
a{
    line-height: 500px; 
    text-align:buttom;
    
}
-->   
        </style>
   </head>
  <body>
<a data-corners="false" href="index.html" data-role="button" data-icon="delete"
          data-iconpos="top" data-theme="a">LIVINGROOM</a> 
     </body>
</html>

Note:
line-height: 500px;  because my buttons are bigger than standard.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got it working:

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
a{
    line-height: 500px; 
    text-align:buttom;

}
-->   
        </style>
   </head>
  <body>
<a data-corners="false" href="index.html" data-role="button" data-icon="delete"
          data-iconpos="top" data-theme="a">LIVINGROOM</a> 
     </body>
</html>
```

Note:
line-height: 500px;  because my buttons are bigger than standard.